# Android Removing an oval section from a canvis

Tags: android

Basically I am trying to draw an O shape. Is there any way (besides just matching up the background colors) that I can make it so I can draw two Oval's and have it so the center oval of the canvas is transparent all the way through to the background of the activity?

Here is what I have so far:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if(mainTimerAngle - 90 < 0){
        mainTimerAngle += 270;
    }

    canvas.drawArc(new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()),
                                          -90, mainTimerAngle-90,true, mainTimerPaint);

    canvas.drawOval(new RectF(barWidth, barWidth, canvas.getWidth() - barWidth,
                                      canvas.getHeight() - barWidth), backgroundPaint);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, by using a `Paint` instance with a [`PorterDuff.Mode.Clear`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html#CLEAR) mode set for the inner oval.

The `CLEAR` mode will basically erase the pixels it draws. As a consequence, you'll want to do the drawing on a dedicated `Bitmap` as opposed to directly on the background of a `View`. If you don't, you'll find that erasing the background directly will lead to black hole.

Here are some links to useful resources. They'll give you an overview of the various modes and their visual results.

- [PorterDuff Modes and Android](http://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/1009/)
- [Alpha Compositing @ Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)

There's also some sample code available in the API demos, which you should be able to find in the Android SDK folder. Be on the lookout for `com.example.android.apis.graphics.Xfermodes`. Alternatively, find [the latest source code for that class here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r2.1/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.java/).

Comment: Question how do I do this with canvas from the ondraw method? If I try to set the bitmap I get an unsupported operation exception.

Comment: The idea is you create a dedicated `Bitmap` for drawing (only once, which you can then reuse) and a new `Canvas` to draw on that bitmap. After having drawn on that bitmap, you can then draw the whole bitmap with the canvas supplied in `onDraw()`. If you take a look at the mentioned `Xfermodes.java` file, you'll find an example that illustrates this concept.

Comment: @Landister: Perhaps somewhat overdue, but as an alternative to above, you could probably also use one of the `Canvas.saveLayer()` methods to draw in an off-screen bitmap.

Comment: `paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR))` for those who just want the codez.